# ELB to ALB Transition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a nodejs aws beanstalk environment which is currently using a elb load balancer configured with an ssl certificate for https request. I am trying to redirect http to https but this can only be done with an alb balancer. When creating this alb balancer I cannot attach my beanstalk instance to this alb but only to the previous elb attached to it? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach your Elastic BeanStalk instance to Application Load Balancer you need to update configurations from Elastic BeanStalk environment.

Below are the steps to update the Elastic BeanStalk environment:

1. Go to your Elastic Beanstalk environment.
2. On the left-hand side select "Configuration" option.
3. Select "Load Balancer" and choose Application Load Balancer, make sure in "Capacity" your "Environment type: Load Balancing, Auto-Scaling".
4. Under the Application Load Balancer, choose option Add Listener, after that provide Port, Protocol, and SSL certificate and make it enabled. So you will redirect your requests http to https.

Note: To provide an SSL certificate, you need to upload certificate contents in the ACM(AWS Certificate Manager).

5. Apply the configuration and you will observe that your instance gets added to your new Application Load Balancer deployed through Elastic BeanStalk environment.